# Disable openlayers map rotation

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to disable several points duplication when rotating map horizontally.
For example here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html when zoomed out, we can see that there is duplication of the view
[image]

I actually do not want this, I need to disable that duplication and have so to say "one world", to be able to drag in only "one world". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrapX: false` needs to be specified for every layer, and even then you can still wrap onto empty space.  In OpenLayers 6 it is easier to restrict the view extent to the default projection extent with the option

```
extent: new View().getProjection().getExtent();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cluster-forked-x73r9

Comment: that the right answer. thanks for help. Sometime it is hard to find necessary option in documentation.

Comment: maybe you know is it possible when rotating a view to rotate markers as well. So is will not be a dublication, but rotation, just markers and clusters jump to new "world"?

Answer (score 2):

Set wrapX option to false when you create the source to prevent this.